# Zero gradients for CuDNNLSTM according to Keras TensorBoard callback

Tags: keras, lstm, tensorboard

I would like to visualize gradients of a seq2seq model using [Keras Tensorboard callback](https://keras.io/callbacks/#tensorboard). If I'm using a regular LSTM cell in my encoder and decoder, I get nice non-zero gradients:

[image]

However if I change the rnn cell to CuDNNLSTM some gradients turn to zero, which seem to be incorrect:

[image]

The both models seem to train correctly.

So, what's wrong with visualisations of CuDNNLSTM gradients? Is there a bug in Keras Tensorboard callback?

Code that I am running is a slightly modified Keras lstm_seq2seq example: https://gist.github.com/nicolas-ivanov/1818d6502d5f1496e5fbe14889eddca1

Comment: Did you find out what's the issue? I'm getting the same but just for the recurrent kernel

Comment: No, not yet. Here is the issue on github: https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/12125 Feel free to upvote it so that the guys from keras team look into it sooner.